# How to validate 2 blank spaces with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

Good afternoon, I have a validation done for when the user leaves only 1 blank space, the idea would be that if you want to enter a word with 2 blank spaces, do not leave it.

Here is the code I have:

```
    if(value && value.length > 1 && value[value.length-1] === ' ') {
       return Promise.reject('Please remove trailing blanks');
    }
```

'value' returns what the user entered character by character.

I am trying to understand this logic as it has been done by another developer.

**The alert should be maintained by typing for example something like "Stack    Code", not only does it appear when I leave the 2 spaces, but the alert is maintained if it remains that way.** (it won't let me separate 'stack code' twice to show you)

From already thank you very much

Comment: why throw an error instead of just fixing it? this is a quick sanitize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could you the regular expression match for that:

```js
value.match(/\s{2,}$/)
```

Comment: I tested this as follows: `if(value.match(/\s{2,}$/)) {
     return Promise.reject('Please remove trailing blanks')` but it didn't work, it doesn't show me the alert

Comment: seems to work better: value.match(/(\s{2,})/g

Answer (score 0):

To check if there are 2 blank spaces at the end you can use:

```
value.endsWith("  ")
```

which returns true or false

Comment: I implemented it just like what Shailendra said but it didn't work, it doesn't give me the alert

Comment: Could you show full code?

Answer (score 0):

For checking 2 blank space you can do this:

`if(value && value.length > 1 && value.endsWith("  "))  { return Promise.reject('Please remove trailing blanks'); }`

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me.

Comment: The alert appears when I write for example, "Stack" I leave two spaces and it appears, but when I leave two spaces and continue writing for example "Stack Code" the alert disappears and it should not disappear since it still has the two blank spaces.

Comment: it won't let me separate 'stack code' twice to show you, but I think you understand what I need